# Suspicious sign in prevented (Heroku, Amazon AWS, Gmail SMTP)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-web-services, smtp, gmail

I occasionally receive emails from Google (`accounts-noreply@google.com`), similar to the following:

```
Subject: Suspicious sign in prevented

Someone recently tried to use an application to sign in to your Google  
Account, ________@gmail.com. We prevented the sign-in attempt in case  
this was a hijacker trying to access your account. Please review the  
details of the sign-in attempt:

Monday, November 19, 2012 8:40:55 PM GMT
IP Address: 184.72.161.49 (amazonaws.com)
Location: Dixmoor, IL, USA

If you do not recognize this sign-in attempt, someone else might be trying  
to access your account. You should sign in to your account and reset your  
password immediately. Find out how at  
http://support.google.com/accounts?p=reset_pw

If this was you, and you want to give this application access to your  
account, complete the troubleshooting steps listed at  
http://support.google.com/mail?p=client_login

Sincerely,
The Google Accounts Team


© 2012 Google Inc. 1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043

You have received this mandatory email service announcement to update you  
about important changes to your Google product or account.
```

Indeed, this was me, as I have an app running on **Heroku** (hence why the IP address is from `amazonaws.com`), and I send email directly from my app via Gmail SMTP (I don't think it should matter, but specifically, I'm using the [gmail_smtp plugin](https://github.com/adamwiggins/gmail_smtp) which I [updated for Rails 3.2](http://code.coneybeare.net/how-to-convert-simple-rails-23-style-plugins)).

Is there a way to avoid this warning, or a way to whitelist known IPs?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Short Answer**

1. In a web browser (perhaps Chrome/Incognito), log into your Gmail account (the one via which you're trying to send email from your app).
2. In another browser tab, open https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha -- and follow the steps.

**Long Answer**

I ended up logging into my Gmail account (mentioned as `________@gmail.com` in the Stackoverflow question above) and saw the following warning:

[image]

[Note: I'm piecing this Answer together after the fact.] Clicking the link **Was it you?**, *I'm pretty sure* I was taken to a page that contained the following, though below it there was a message and button about adding another application to the list:

[image]

[Again, *I'm pretty sure*...] Clicking the button on that page brought me to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha -- which looks like this:

[image]

Clicking **Continue** brought me to another page:

[image]

At that point I just went to my app, and made it send an email.

Note: for general live-testing of email in my app, I have a view at `triggers#index` with two buttons that send `PUT` requests to these actions: `triggers#send_email` and `triggers#raise_exception`. This enables an admin to go to `/triggers` and *send an email* or *raise an exception* to test if the production system is working correctly as far as being able to send email is concerned. Raising an exception in any of my apps emails details to me via [exception_notification](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification).

Comment: If one is trying to use gmail's SMTP server from AWS, its crucial to allow the IP address in google's servers, by using this: "https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha", or else it won't be able to use the SMTP server.

Comment: This answer appears to be out-dated now. In your Google account security settings, you're looking for "Application Specific Passwords". You need to create one and use it (instead of your master password) when accessing your Gmail via your application.

Comment: @DavidTuite - Thanks for the note. I will update this answer when I next receive this notice and have to go through the process.

Comment: Actually, I just used the solution above and it worked perfectly. Perhaps the gmail interface has changed but the url is currently still accepted.

Comment: I had to visit https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha before I could successfully configure gmail to use smtp.gmail.com to send mail from another email address i own.  Amazing that this is not documented somewhere prominent :-(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when I tried sending emails through Gmail SMTP using PHP. You shoud complete the troubleshooting steps provided at the end of the email.

Answer (score 2):

On your Gmail mail box look at the bottom right corner and you can see a Details button. Click on it and then on the pop up window change the suspicious warning settings.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working in dev with **Rails 4** i had to enable access for less secure apps.

Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps while signed on to your gmail account and click 'turn on'. Note, this enables access for less secure apps which could come with unintended consequences.

> Some apps and devices use less secure sign-in technology, which makes
>   your account more vulnerable. You can turn off access for these apps,
>   which we recommend, or turn on access if you want to use them despite
>   the risks.

Answer (score 2):

To get this working in Rails 4, in addition to enabling access for less secure apps, as described already (Visit https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps while signed on to your gmail account and click 'turn on'. Note, this enables access for less secure apps which could come with unintended consequences.), 
one more step may be required in some cases, if account access is still blocked.
If this is the case, also visit https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click continue, to enable account access to send via gmail SMTP.

Credit to [Steve Polito](http://www.stevepolitodesign.com/blog/drupal-configure-smtp-module-work-gmail-updated)